# What are Boom Boxes and how can I get them on a regular basis?

Tags: wildstar

In Wildstar, I have seen that there are some housing items that can only be gotten through so called Boom Boxes. I read online that they where given out in the Open Beta, but what about now? How can I get one and can I get them regularly? I also read that Deluxe Owners would get them, but I could not find this offer in the [NC Soft Store](https://shop.wildstar-online.com/product/deluxeUpgrade) on the Upgrade option for Wildstar.

Can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boom-Boxes are items that can be obtained once per day. [The contents of Boom-Boxes are randomly generated and can range from anything like Mounts and Mount Customization Sets, to Costumes, Dyes, or Crafting Materials](https://support.wildstar-online.com/entries/69281873-Boom-Box-FAQ-UPDATED-6-5).

Boom-Boxes can now only be obtained by playing on the Wildstar test server (PTR) when Carbine is requesting for assistance in testing a new feature. They will announce what days are eligible to be earning Boom-Boxes on their forums and what activity they would like you to participate in (Examples: [Daggerstone Pass](https://forums.wildstar-online.com/forums/index.php?/topic/98122-play-on-the-ptr-get-boomboxes-july-18th-2014/), [Blighthaven Quests](https://forums.wildstar-online.com/forums/index.php?/topic/86103-play-on-the-ptr-get-boomboxes/)). Unfortunately there is no set days where you can earn Boom-Boxes, it is based entirely off of Carbine's announcements.

In regards to Deluxe Owners getting Boom-Boxes, I believe they are referring to that if you pre-order you got access to the beta, which gave you 3 Boom-Boxes per day of logging on.